# np.arange() can't be squared properly

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying stuff in PyCharm so I wrote a simple piece of code including :

```
xlist = np.arange(99995,99996)
print(xlist*xlist)
>>> array([1409065433])
```

As you can see, the answer is incorrect! I should obtain 9999000025. I stumbled upon this because I originally wrote :

```
xlist = np.arange(0,100000)

for x in xlist:
    print(x)
    z = x * x
    print(z)
print(xlist*xlist)
```

And got many weird results, including **negative values** for x around 90000.

Three of my friends tested this piece of code and two obtained the same results as me (on windows) and the other got it right, on Linux, so it seems to be OS dependent...

Anybody knows what the hell is going on?

Comment: Python3 ints are arbitrary-precision. Numpy ints are 32 or 64-bit by default, so they can't be arbitrarily large and overflows can happen.

Comment: Specify: `dtype=np.int64` before doing this.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Not necessarily 64-bit. It depends on the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

9999000025 doesn't fit in a 32-bit int. Unlike regular Python ints, NumPy data types are fixed-size, and there are limits to the values they can hold.

The fix here would be to specify `dtype=np.int64`.

```
x = np.arange(99995,99996, dtype=np.int64)
print(x * x)
Out[155]: array([9999000025])
```